# Error install Charm Crypto 0.50 Error:---> make: *** [Makefile:29: all] Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.7, charm-crypto

1. Charm installation problem solution needs suggestions.

Hello, I am not a well good expert I have to face the problem by installing charm crypto 0.50 documentation using ubuntu 21.10 using python 3.7.1 and got the error make file 29 and segmentation error.
I have to try possible techniques by using the charm crypto dev zip file from GitHub as form here  https://github.com/JHUISI/charm
Procedure I follow for charm installation from https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/447934026
I have successfully installed Openssl OpenSSL 1.1.1n , gmp-6.2.0.tar.bz2, pbc-0.5.14 for charm sudo ./configure.sh as follows.

```
(env55) ali@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/charm-dev$ sudo ./configure.sh
[sudo] password for ali: 
Install prefix    /usr/local
data directory    /usr/local/share/charm
binary directory  /usr/local/bin
library directory /usr/local/lib
config directory  /usr/local/etc
Source path       /usr/local/src/charm-dev
CFLAGS            -O2 -g 
CHARM_CFLAGS       -m64 -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes  -fstack-protector-all -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits
LDFLAGS           -m64 
make              make
python            /usr/local/bin/python3
python-config     /usr/local/bin/python3-config
build_ext options build_ext 
install           install
host CPU          x86_64
wget              /usr/bin/wget
gprof enabled     no
profiler          no
static build      no
-Werror enabled   no
integer module    yes
ecc module        yes
pairing module    yes
disable benchmark no
libm found        yes
libgmp found      yes
libpbc found      yes
libcrypto found   yes
Documentation     no
```

**The Error during Sudo make as follows as can see follow for set -x and set +x from https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/Makefile **

```
(env55) ali@ubuntu:/usr/local/src/charm-dev$ sudo make
Setup build/staging directories
set -x
set +x
Building the Charm Framework
/usr/local/bin/python3 setup.py build  
make: *** [Makefile:29: all] Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 : The system python is 3.9.4 . ... Why use an alien python version ? .... Ubuntu 22.04 example (pbc-0.5.14 + libgmp-dev) : `cd charm/ && ./configure.sh && make && sudo make install`: No errors.

Comment: **21.10** (behaves as 22.04) → Python3 is now 3.9.7. ... pbc-0-5-14: `./configure --prefix=/usr/ --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. ... `sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip flex bison libssl-dev libgmp-dev` ..... and `charm` installs with no errors.

Comment: I have successfully installed charm using python3.9 but I am using some code that only supports python3.7  and python 3.9 which is downgrading python3.7 and again installing charm. which causes the make:*** [Makefile:29: all] Segmentation fault error.

Comment: As I refer here myself https://python-forum.io/thread-36978.html to the error and you have to look at why we need to downgrade python3.7  and install charm again

Comment: Suggest : Use an OS with system python3.7, e.g. Debian 10 :  `python3.7.3` .

Comment: Yes, you are right to use operation system pyhton3.7  but also Ubuntu18 or lower not ununtu 20+.